# LUA для PHP  разработчика

Tags: lua, php

Есть ли смысл PHP разработчику изучать Lua - интерпретируемый язык программирования.

есть есть, то для чего его лучше использовать?

Может ли он являться альтернативой, например Python?

Comment: Интересный вопрос... Если для себя писать - то какая разница на чем? А если для кого-то - то есть смысл оценить спрос на разработчиков новой среды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua это отличный встраиваемый язык. лучше всего применять совместно с С++. А вот если брять отдельно, то я таки отдам предпочтение Питону перлу и т.д

Answer (score 1):

Где-то мелькнула информация, что Lua в последнее время очень набирает обороты в качестве языка веб-программирования. Относительно алтернативы питону: меня мучает подозрение, что в настоящее питон имеет более развитую базу разных библиотек и модулей.

Answer (score 0):

lua - очень легкий встраиваемый язык, в настоящее время используется в разработке социальных игр компанией [mail.ru](http://mail.ru). Есть перспективы в более обширном плане и еще на нем пишут хранимые процедуры в nosql хранилищах: redis, tokyotyrant,tarantool - которые активно исп в WEB.
рекомендую обратить на него внимание